# Started getting ssl exceptions on my nexus S (android 9), ok on other devices

Tags: android

I'm making an https connection to my webserver. Haven't changed anything server-side, or client-side. Today, on an android 9 device (the nexus S), all my connections started throwing this exception. Same app works ok on my nexus 1 and other test devices + emulator. I'm not sure what's going on here, anyone else seeing this? I'm not doing any custom https work:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: 
Read error: ssl=0x3100a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:786)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:410)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
```

Thanks

Comment: Not that it helps you but yes, I am also getting this in my apps on Android 2.3.3, still trying to figure out why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in 2.3.3. For another method to download over SSL, see [SSLProtocolException when reading https responses on Android 2.3.3 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852492/sslprotocolexception-when-reading-https-responses-on-android-2-3-3-devices/6950339#6950339)