# SSLProtocolException making a https connection

Tags: android, ssl

I have a SSLProtocolException when I'm making a https connection to my webserver. I only have this exception in Android 2.3 Gingebread; the same code works fine in all other Android versions. Is there any problem with this Android version?

I also have opened a bug report with Google: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16121&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

I have attached the Exception:

> WARN/System.err(6218): javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x3c97e8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   WARN/System.err(6218):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
>   WARN/System.err(6218):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:788)
>   WARN/System.err(6218):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.FixedLengthInputStream.read(FixedLengthInputStream.java:44)
>   WARN/System.err(6218):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:319)
>   WARN/System.err(6218):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   WARN/System.err(6218):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   WARN/System.err(6218):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

Comment: Doesn't look like there's much info out there right now about this issue. I'd recommend opening a bug with Google. Please see this SO question for what looks to be same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070512/started-getting-ssl-exceptions-on-my-nexus-s-android-9-ok-on-other-devices

Comment: Agree, you are not the first one to get this on Android 2.3.3, it is probably a regression in the OS and as such there is probably not much we can do except remove support for Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Seems like making the buffer size 4k works? if this is similar to the other issue.  Do you have any code?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852492/sslprotocolexception-when-reading-https-responses-on-android-2-3-3-devices/6950339#6950339 ?  Reference same Android Bug #16121. Neither provides sample code to confirm.

Comment: This issue had resolved. You can see the google report by this link: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16121&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: Actually, the issue was resolved in 2.3.4 (I assume) It still occurs in 2.3.3 - as testing in the emulator.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852492/sslprotocolexception-when-reading-https-responses-on-android-2-3-3-devices/6950339#6950339

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SSLSocketFactory` to read from the socket directly. I posted a test-case with commented code here: [SSLProtocolException when reading https responses on Android 2.3.3 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852492/sslprotocolexception-when-reading-https-responses-on-android-2-3-3-devices/6998629#6998629)

Answer (score 0):

check whether server want client authentication.In my case in tomcat server.xml clientAuth="true",so error was there so change i change it to false.